# Stream of Integers arriving at specified interval need to look sorted

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Interview question: There is a stream of Integers that arrives at specified intervals (say every 20 sec). Which Container of STL would you use to store them so that the Integers look sorted? My reply was map/set when there is no duplicate or multimap/multiset when there is duplicate. Any better answer if exists?

Comment: Appear sorted *when* ? If that stream has an eventual end and *then* the results are displayed, a `std::map<int, unsigned int>` would work, with the pair-second being the occurrence count to preserve duplicates, else a `std::set<>`. If the stream is perpetual or if the values are to be emitted with some sort of intermediate delay, the answer is none, since the language committee inconveniently left the crystal ball container out of the standard.

Comment: Why map? That needs pairs of related values. you have only single integers.

Comment: "look sorted", what exactly does that mean? Either they are sorted, then they look sorted, or they are not and then don't.

Comment: @Urich: You r right. A bit confusing. I failed to ask if it should be held in a sorted manner. Set uses RBL tree to store elements but they are not held in a sorted manner inside the container. But when you print out the contents, they appear in sorted order as iterator perform a in-order traversal on it.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense to me: If the elements in the tree were not ordered, how could an in-order traversal output them as sorted? Anyhow, chances are that you were expected to ask the right questions when faced with an incomplete specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `multiset` if you want to ***preserve*** duplicates. If you don't want to preserve duplicates, use a `set`.

Answer (score 2):

If it's only being updated every 20 seconds, it probably doesn't matter a whole lot (unless it goes for so long that the set of integers becomes tremendously huge).

If you had data coming in a lot faster, there are alternatives that might be worth considering. One would be to use a couple of vectors. As data arrives, just push it onto one of the vectors. When you need to do an in-order traversal, sort that newly arrived data, and merge with the other vector of existing (already-sorted data). That'll give you results in order, which you can then write out to another vector, and start the same cycle again.

The big advantage here is that you're dealing with contiguous data instead of individually allocated nodes. Even with a possibility of three vectors in use at a time, your total memory usage is likely to be about equal (or possibly even less than) that of using a `set` or `multiset`.

Another possibility to consider (that's a bit of a hybrid between the two) would be something like a B+ tree. This is still a tree, so you can do in-order insertions with logarithmic complexity, but you have all the data in the leaf nodes (which are fairly large) so you get at least a reasonable amount of contiguous access as well.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain a **sorted** list of integers streaming I would use **std::priority_queue** with any underlying container (vector or deque depending on the particular use).

You can keep **push()** ing to the priority_queue and use **top()** and **pop()** to retrieve in the sorted order.

Comment: I agree with you, O(logn) push, and O(nlogn) sort

Comment: @Chammika: Insertion takes O(logn) in RBL tree (which set uses). And then do a tree sort which would take O(nlogn). Isn't same as PQ?

Comment: I would prefer set because if the stream of Integers need to be printed, then set is the best data structure as it does not have to sort the content before printing. Since it is arranged in balanced BST structure, I think iterator will perform a in-order traversal on it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer should be `std::set` . `std::map<key, value>` has to consider when there is a pairs of data as `<key, value>`  and it need to be sorted according to the value of `key`

In same way if you have to consider duplicates, use `std::multiset` and `std::multimap` according to  type of  data.

Comment: My thought was to let the values of all the keys in the map be zero. Does not this become similar to std::set implementation?

Comment: @DIVAKARVENKATRAMANI Values of all the keys will not be zero by default.

Comment: @DIVAKARVENKATRAMANI, items in `std::map` are sorted by key not by value. If you use `std::map`, the numbers that you read from your stream have to be the keys of the map. The values can by anything.

Comment: @Sahu. I meant what you had written.